# UIImageView subclass' image property

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

I have this in my `config.h`

```
#define SomeImage [UIImage imageNamed:@"some_pic.png"]
```

I have a class named `Something` subclass of `UIImageView`, imported `config.h` in `Something.h`

In `Something.m` `initWithFrame` method:

```
self.image = SomeImage;
```

The problem is when i create a new `Something` and add it to superview , I can't see anything.

I think I can handle the problem with `initWithImage` but couldn't figure out why my code isn't working.

Comment: Try [[UIImage alloc] initWithImage:@""]

Comment: Did you check the return value? How are you adding the `UIImageView` to the view hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mentioned frame for your `Something.m` ?

It should work fine, example

```
Something *something = [[Something alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];
[self.view addSubview:something];
```

**Something.m**

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }

    self.image = SomeImage;

    return self;
}
```